# PHP/Oracle Connectivity randomly "drops out"

Tags: apache-2.2, php, oracle

Here's the current situation - I have two web servers (for now named A and B) and two database servers (named C and D). The web servers are quite old, and are running an early version of Apache 2 + PHP4, while the DB servers are running Oracle 9i and 10g respectively. We're experiencing a strange problem connecting (via PHP code) to database A while on web server B only. Web server A has no issues at all... Randomly, web server B will report a "Not connected to Oracle" error (3114). I can't see a real pattern with this, but refreshing a few times seems to fix the issue. Apparently there are no drop-outs on the network interface, which leads me to believe that there's some misconfiguration between PHP/Apache and Oracle (which uses connection pooling). We're running SunOS 5.8...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Сheck parameter "Maximum Idle Time" in oracle user profile and SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME in sqlnet.ora

See the logs and .trc files on the Oracle server, to determine the cause of the disconnects.

P.S. Connection pooling may be unstable in earlier versions of Oracle 10G